# Why derive Typeable for this type

Tags: haskell, xmonad

In `xmonad` source code, I find:

```
data Resize     = Shrink | Expand   deriving Typeable
```

I can't figure out why this needs to derive from `Typeable`

I saw a famous [blog post](https://chrisdone.com/posts/data-typeable) by Chrisdone which explains the various usages of Typeable. But I can't find any of the scenarios in `xmonad` source code.

Any hint?

Comment: Is it strictly necessary? What happens if you remove the `deriving` clause and *recompile*? Some programmers just add some `deriving` statements such that later, it is easy to use these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a remnant of older versions of GHC. Nowadays `Typeable` is derived for all types automatically and `deriving Typeable` does nothing but is allowed for backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

Typeable can always be derived for all types, so... why not? The xmonad code may not make use of the `Typeable` instance, but users might want to.

Note that `Typeable` is a class whose instances should generally *not* be defined by hand.

Comment: As of ghc 7.8, you can't define such instances by hand.